# How to find files with given character encoding?

Tags: search, software-rec, encoding

I am using Windows XP. I am looking for a tool that for given directory will find all files having particular character encoding (like UTF-8). Do you know such a tool?

Comment: There's no completely reliable way to detect any file's encoding in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

This tool works great. Check it out. It shows all files and their encodings for a folder.

http://encodingchecker.codeplex.com/releases/view/59420

There is also this, for bulk changing files to UTF8.

http://www.rotatingscrew.com/utfcast.aspx

Answer (score 5):

In general this is not possible - apart from the special case of UTF-8 text files with a Byte Order Mark. Since the name of the encoding is not stored in the text file the only way to tell, for example, CP437 from CP850 would be to make a guess based on a statistical analysis of the whole file, looking at frequency of certain character pairs etc.

Solaris users have [auto_ef](http://manpages.unixforum.co.uk/man-pages/unix/solaris-10-11_06/1/auto_ef-man-page.html) but, so far as I know, there isn't a Windows port.

Perl users have [Encode::Guess](http://search.cpan.org/~dankogai/Encode-2.40/lib/Encode/Guess.pm)

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) "The newer versions of the unix File command attempt to do a basic detection of character encoding. (also available on cygwin and mac)"

None of the above will be 100% reliable. If your files are definitely all in one of a handful of known encodings you may be able to do better.

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows this is possible by searching for the right [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM), on the condition that the files were created with a BOM.

You would need a search program for that.
One possibility may be [Grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) and search using the beginning of file operator (^^).